# MSACCESS - How to save form's record values on buttonClick event avoiding normal auto save on a control.lostfocus

Tags: forms, ms-access, recordset, post-processing

I have a form with some txtboxes linked to a query.
The normal behavior is when i change the value of one of these txtboxes and i tab to another control,
the record is automatically updated with its new value.

I want to avoid this behavior and demand to a `buttonClick` event the record saving procedure.

I tried with the form's `wait for post processing` property but it doesn't work..
help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no, editing values and textboxes on a form does NOT touch, or write the record back to the underlying forms data source. The term in Access is called a bound form.

The record is pulled from the table, and the data fills out the controls on the form. At that point, you can edit data, but the forms data has NOT been written back to the table.

Hitting tab key to exit a control will NOT normally write the data back to the  the table.

However, if the control on the form is the  LAST control, and you hit tab?

Well, Access DOES save the record if you  move to the next record.

So hitting tab key ONLY moves to the next control and DOES NOT save the data you JUST entered into that text box (or any bound control).

However:
If you are on the LAST control on the form and it tab?
What occurres next will DEPEND on your forms settings.
If you used the defaults, then hitting tab key will MOVE to the next record. Now of course if you move to the next record, then the data is saved and written back to the table.

So tab ONLY saves the data if you are on the LAST CONTROL on the form.

However, you can change the setting of the tab key WHEN on the last control.

In the forms property sheet, "other" tab, you have what is called the cycle property.

this setting:

[image]

So, if you have this as "All Records"?
Then for ease of data entry, you can edit on a form, and hit tab for the next control. But when on the LAST control on the form, if you hit tab, you move to the next record. Thus a user can edit data with keyboard only, and for lots of data entry, it is a great feature.
And on a continues form (multiple items), then when on the last row, hitting tab will move to the next record, and hence next row. Again, a GREAT feature for editing data.

So, if you DO NOT want tab to save your  data?

Then change the above to Current record. What will occur is that when the user hits tab, AND you are on the last control? The cursor will jump back up to the TOP of the form, and NOT SAVE OR WRITE the data to the table.

in effect, hitting tab will go round and round forever on the CURRENT record.

So, tab DOES NOT save the data to the table UNLESS on that last control on the form.

Editing data, check boxes, combo boxes etc. DOES NOT save nor write the forms data back to the table.

Now, if you move off the record? Then yes a automatic save does occur. But, by changing that cycle, then the user will NOT accident move off the reocrd.

The data for the current record is ALSO saved if you close the form.

What about a button on the form that saves the data?

You can place a button on a form, and save (write) the forms data to a table with this code:

```
if me.Dirty = True then me.Dirty = False
```

So, the above is how you can have a button on the form write/save the data to the table.

But JUST hitting tab will NOT save the data. The exception of course is if you are on the last control, and the forms cycle property is = All Records.

if you change that to Current record, then they can hit tab all day long for hours on end, and the forms data will NOT be saved, and will NOT be written to the table.

Comment: is it possible that the data will save when i click TAB because the form is a splitform?

Comment: Only if you hitting tab MOVES OUT of the current form area. If hitting tab moves from the main area to the area below with MANY records? Yes, a save can occur. If you are JUST editing data in text box etc.? Then NO a simple hit of tab will NOT save the data to the table. Until the data is saved the user can hit Esc (one time) to undo changes to the control, and hitting Esc a 2nd time will undo ALL changes to the record. And you can use the ribbon edit area also hit un-do. But until the user leaves the record, or saves it, tab will not in general save the record. Change cycle to current record.

Comment: but it seems to save the data anyway if i press tab to next txtbox.. mistery..

Comment: No, the save of data will not occur until user actions cause the WHOLE record to be saved. A record is ONE thing. And it is saved in ONE single operation. Now if you toss up a form, edit and hit tab? The record not saved. But if you close the form and then go look at the table? The ACT of closing the form caused the save, not you hitting tab.

Comment: aha.. so closing the form will save all the changes made on the record. thanks

Comment: so whats the meaning of wait for post processing form's property then?

Comment: The hint text  explains that feature is in  regards to data macros. Those are table level code triggers - often used with SharePoint. And besides, even if the option was to "wait" for some time until that code finishes, it still have zero to do with hitting tab to go to the next text box on a form which does not save data. So hitting tab to move would not fire any post processing code anyway.

Comment: closing form saves data. Yes, so does moving to another record. You can put a message box and prompt to save data in the forms before up-date event. But then what happens if you close a form, and the the save prompt fires. You then realize that all your editing you done you still want. So, if you answer no to save, then does the form still close and you lose all your changes? So, you have to decide if you want to deal with and write code to save the data, or have access do it for you.